# I am passing context to my constructor but a service still wants a class name according to ide

Tags: java, android, class, android-context

I created a class and in the constructor I give it context.

```
public class DownloadHandler {

        private Context mContext;
        private String filename;
        private String remotePath;

        public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

//Constructor====================================================================

        public DownloadHandler(String rp, String f, Context c) throws Exception {
            mContext = c;
            remotePath = rp;
            filename = f;
        }
...
```

The IDE is complaining that my progressDialog expects a class.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            //==============HERE================================
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext.this);
            //==================================================
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

I thought I was doing this right....

Comment: why mContext.this ?, should be "mContext"

Comment: you mean `this.mContext` ?

Comment: @Hacketo... ohhhhh! I get confused as to when to use the .this

Comment: @silversunhunter.  -1- `this` is an object, you can move forward from there: this.myMemberVariable, ...  -2- I try to avoid the situation by not referencing `this` explicitly when I can.  If you have a member variable `_foobar` and do not have a local variable of the same name, then in your method `_foobar` actually means `this._foobar`.  (many people use the convention that "_" prefix is used ONLY for member variables; there are several advantages, clarity one of them). --cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hacketo wrote:

> why `mContext.this` ?, should be "`mContext`"

@Mohammad Rahchamani wrote:

> you mean `this.mContext`

@BrianT explained:

> 1. this is an object, you can move forward from there: `this.myMemberVariable`
> 2. I try to avoid the situation by not referencing this explicitly when I can. If you have a member variable `_foobar` and do not have a local variable of the same name, then in your method `_foobar` actually means this: `_foobar`. (many people use the convention that "`_`" prefix is used ONLY for member variables; there are several advantages, clarity one of them).

Comment: ([Answered in comments and converted to a community wiki.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))